# Function I just made giving me an 'is not defined' error

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a function to count how many times a number appears in a list of 5 random numbers and then produce that in a new list. It seems to be fine up till the end when I want to test it where it says dice is not defined when I make it print the countVals function. I have a previous function which defines dice as a list of 5 random numbers.

```
def rollDice() :
    dice = []
    for i in range(5) :
        dice.append(random.randint(1,6))        
    return (dice)
print(rollDice()) #Here is the previous function as requested

def countVals(dice):
    present = 0 #present is how many times each number appears in dice
    totals = []
    for i in range (6):
        for j in range(5):
            if dice[j] == (j+1) :
                present += 1
        totals[j] = present
    return(totals)
print(countVals(dice)) #getting the following error on this line:
```

print(countVals(dice))
NameError: name 'dice' is not defined

I think I'm just having a mind blank but how would I define dice? I thought it would've been defined in my previous function which creates the list of 5 numbers called dice

Am I missing something important with dice that should be in the main code?

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the full traceback.

Comment: Well, did you define `dice` anywhere?

Comment: And if `dice` is supposed to be a list, you cannot use it as a function; you'd use `dice[j]`, not `dice(j)`.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: no foundation of basic understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the variable `dice` which is not defined in the namespace where you try to use it. You have `dice` in `rollDice` but this variable is not available outside of this function.

You can use the following code to bind the return value to a new variable and work with it afterwards.

```
dice = rollDice()
print(countVals(dice))
```

If you just need the values in `countVals` and nowhere else in the outer namespace you can use this shortcut.

```
print(countVals(rollDice()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `dice` previously?

You need to assign a value to dice.